# SVM: cost sensitive learning vs. the Cost parameter

Tags: svm, unbalanced-classes

I have an imbalanced dataset (99%-1%) and am trying different approaches to optimize the F1 score.

My question is about SVM and the possible difference between tuning the Cost parameter and to use SVM as a the cost sensitive learner.

My guess is that:

- In Cost sensitive learning the misclassification costs for the minority class are higher, hence misclassifications are penalized. This is often sketched with an Cost matrix.
- Increasing the Cost parameter in SVM leads to a smaller margin and a greater penalty to classifications within the margin.

To be specific: I think that the methods are different, but I'm unsure because of the terminologie and both of the Cost penalize misclassifications.

Hopefully someone can explain me if they are the same or different and why